# How to construct the FSelectInstanceSingleCrit in mlr3FSelect?

Tags: mlr3

I copied the code from mlr3book:

```
library(mlr3verse)

task = tsk("pima")
print(task)
learner = lrn("classif.rpart")
hout = rsmp("holdout")
measure = msr("classif.ce")

evals20 = trm("evals", n_evals = 20)

instance = FSelectInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task,
  learner = learner,
  resampling = hout,
  measure = measure,
  terminator = evals20
)
```

But I always got this error:

```
Error in initialize(...) : unused argument (store_x_domain = FALSE)
```

Is there anything with this code? Could someone give some suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Update your packages with `update.packages()`. You use an old version of mlr3fselect.